# Не работает проверка на корректность ввода

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Существует код, в котором нужно ввести номер домашней работы. Суть в том, что работ, скажем, 5. Так вот при вводе любого значения кроме 1-5 программа должна вывести: "Введённые данные некорректны".
Я попытался реализовать проверку следующим образом:

```cpp
int taskNumber;
bool isCorrectNumber;

while (true) {
    cout << "Для просмотра заданий введите номер задания (1-5)" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "№1 - задание \"Имя\"" << endl;
    cout << "№2 - задание \"Арифметика\" "<< endl;
    cout << "№3 - задание \"Уравнение\" "<< endl;
    cout << "№4 - задание \"Ещё уравнение\" "<< endl;
    cout << "№5 - задание \"Лампа со шторой\" "<< endl;
    cout << endl;

    isCorrectNumber = 0;
    do {
        cin >> taskNumber;
        if (taskNumber > 0 && taskNumber < 6) {
            isCorrectNumber = 1;
        }
        else {
            taskNumber = 0;
            cout << "Вы ввели некорректный номер задания, вам необходимо ввести значение от 1 до 5 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)" << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    } while (isCorrectNumber == 0);

    cout << "Ты вышел из ментальной тюрьмы, ежже" << endl;
}
```

Суть в том, что при вводе числа, которое не является номером задания всё работает как надо и начинается новый ввод. Однако если ввести какое-то слово, то консоль начнёт спамить `"Вы ввели некорректный номер задания, вам необходимо ввести значение от 1 до 5 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)"`

Comment: Так а что вы ожидаете?

Comment: @dIm0n ожидаю, что можно будет заново ввести какое-то значение, чтобы снова начался if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного переделал оответ Гарри - надо бы еще проверять на ввод дабла.
из Моих изменений

1. добавил чек на дабл
2. использую стрингвью а не голый указатель
3. использую лимиты
4. логически разделил ввод и чек на инт и чек на лимит

Вот измененный код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <string_view>

int GetIntFromCin(std::string_view prompt) {
  double input{0x0};
  while (true) {
    input = 0x0;
    std::cout << prompt << " : " << std::flush;
    if ((std::cin >> input).good()) {
      if (input == static_cast<int>(input)) {
        break;
      }
      std::cout << std::endl << "You Inter a Float or Double! Try agane!" << std::endl << std::flush;
    }
    if (std::cin.fail()) {
      std::cin.clear();
      std::cout << std::endl << "Wrong Retry please:" << std::endl << std::flush;
    }
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
  }

  return static_cast<int>(input);
}

int GetIntFromCinWithLimits(std::string_view prompt, int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(), int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::max()) {
  int ret{0};
  while (true) {
    ret = GetIntFromCin(prompt);
    if (ret < min || ret > max) {
      std::cout << std::endl << "Wrong By limits!" << std::endl << std::flush;
      continue;
    }
    break;
  }

  return ret;
}

int main() {
  int val = GetIntFromCinWithLimits("Enter nun", 0, 100);
  std::cout << "You enter a " << val << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Чего бы тогда не пойти ещё дальше и не сделать шаблонную функцию, чтобы можно было вводить не только `int`'ы но и всякие `long`'и с `unsigned long long`'ами? ;)

Comment: @wololo такой задачи нет)

Answer (score 5):

Потому что если вы вводите *не число* - оно остается в буфере ввода, а поток переходит в состояние fail - и никакого чтения уже больше нет...

Вот, возьмите готовый вариант с проверкой корректности ввода и диапазона:

```
int inputInt(const char * prompt, int m = INT_MIN, int M = INT_MAX)
{
    int N;
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << prompt << " (целое от " << m << " до " << M << "): " << std::flush;
        if ((std::cin >> N).good() && (m <= N) && (N <= M)) return N;
        if (std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cout << "Неверный ввод, повторите.\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Число вне допустимого диапазона значений. Повторите ввод.\n";
        }
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    }
}

a = inputInt("Введите размер массива",1,10);
```

Comment: За что отвечает первый параметр? char* promt

Comment: Как и следует из названия - приглашение :) Вы бы запустили и посмотрели...

Comment: @Harry почему не string_view? и почему не std::numeric_limits? + а где чек на ввод дабла или флота?

Comment: @Maggot Если хотите - допишите. Это просто скопированный из более старого ответа код, который я писал для ленивого студента еще тогда, когда о `string_view` (кстати, как по мне - оно тут ни к чему) и не слышали :) Конечно, можно накрутить тут шашечки и расписать их, как космические ракеты, под хохлому... но человеку надо просто ехать :)

Comment: @Harry ну я опубликовал изменения в Вашем коде)))) не ну просто у вас слишком конкретное решение что плохо - решения надо искать все же в универсальных решениях)

Answer (score 3):

```
int taskNumber;
bool isCorrectNumber = false;

do{
    cout << "Для просмотра заданий введите номер задания (1-5)" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "№1 - задание \"Имя\"" << endl;
    cout << "№2 - задание \"Арифметика\" " << endl;
    cout << "№3 - задание \"Уравнение\" " << endl;
    cout << "№4 - задание \"Ещё уравнение\" " << endl;
    cout << "№5 - задание \"Лампа со шторой\" " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> taskNumber;
    if (taskNumber > 0 && taskNumber < 6) {
        isCorrectNumber = true;
    }
    else {
        taskNumber = 0;
        cout << "Вы ввели некорректный номер задания, вам необходимо ввести значение от 1 до 5 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)" << endl;
        cout << endl;
    };

    cout << "Ты вышел из ментальной тюрьмы, ежже" << endl;
} while (!isCorrectNumber);
```

прошу заметить я саму логику ввода не менял , я изменил ее конструкцию